# python: Looking for elements in a list

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So the thing I'm trying to do is I need to look for a certain thing in a list

```
 movieOneList = []  
  def listcreator(sheet):
        for row in movie_ID.rows[1:]:
             if row[1].value.find(movieOne) != -1:
                 movieOneList.append( print("Found your movie! MovieID={0}, Title={1}".format(row[0].value, row[1].value)))
```

The code works by you type in a certain movie and then openpyxl goes through the worksheet in excel, looks for the movie and then prints the first two rows which is the movie ID and the movie name.

What i can't figure out is how do i grab the movie ID and put it in another list so i can look for it in another workbook

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the `print` function returns `None`, meaning that for each movie found, you append `None` to `movieOneList`. Instead, try `movieOneList.append((row[0].value, row[1].value))`, which will append a tuple containing the ID and Title of each movie that it finds to `movieOneList`. If you also want to print the results, you can move the `print("Found...)` to after the `movieOneList.append(...)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: This does help alot but I need to grab the movie ID from the list and put it in another list. How would i do that?

Comment: Why not just skip the middleman and append just the ID to that other list directly?